# Drop down menu (list) not compatible with I.E.?

Tags: php, html, css, drag-and-drop, drop-down-menu

Fixed by adding: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`
The problem was that IE rendered it as Quirk mode, So after the suggestions I disabled it and my page was perfect! So I added that meta so it will show up good in IE 9.

My drop down menu is compatible with FF and CHROME but not with IE. 
Using PHP/HTML/CSS

[JSFiddle: link](http://jsfiddle.net/F4LLCON/wWSjX/)

The problem really is: 
When I remove > it will show onze media. But there is no drop down menu (list).
So the actual question is: Does I.E. support `<ul><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul>?`

[image]
***[IMG LINK for larger IMG](http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/9350/dropdown.png)***

```
#media > a{
    height:49px;
    width:85px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image : URL(images/menu/media_normal.png );
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}   
#media > a:hover{
    height:49px;
    width:85px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image : URL(images/menu/media_selected.png );

}


<li id="media"><a href="media.php"></a>  
<ul>
<?php   
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `apps` ");
while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    ?>
    <li>
    <?php
    $meer = $query_row['TITLE'];
    $desc_inject = '';
    $sub_string = substr($desc_inject, 0, 200);
    echo $sub_string." " . '' . '<a href="applink.php?id='. $query_row["ID"] . '">' . $meer . '</a>';
    ?>
    </li>
    <br />
    <?php
}
?>
</ul> 
</li>
```

This will get the titles from my database (MySQL) and parse it in the drop down of *menu*.
In chrome and FF it shows up perfect, but in IE it does not even show the tab *menu*.
If I delete > between #media > a {} it shows the tab *menu* but not the hover, I also need to delete > between #media > a:hover {} then it shows the hover.
But the drop down menu does not work.

is

```
<ul><li><ul><li></li></ul></li></ul>
```

compatible with IE? I have the latest IE.

Comment: Can you go into your source and copy the generated menu HTML and relative CSS into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to reproduce your bug please.

Comment: I did, but you can't see the images of course. But when I hover above onze media it shows the drop down in JSFiddle. 
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/F4LLCON/wWSjX/). 
Oh I see, when I go in JSFiddle in I.E. it does not show it, only in Chrome JSFiddle.

Comment: Yes I just uploaded it: [link](http://syndicateplus.com/script/syp/index.php)

Comment: Nothing happens, I use it to get each title on a new line, but as andyb  said, IE makes quirks mode out of my page. I disabled it and my page is showing up good. I need to see how I can disable quirks by default

Comment: If that is the case, the you just need to fix your [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsyndicateplus.com%2Fscript%2Fsyp%2Findex.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: No, it is fixed now :D I've added  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /> and it changed my page and shows is up like Chrome now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invalid markup is forcing IE into [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and therefore will probably render support for the child selector inactive (as @Sarfraz suggested). Forcing IE9 into Standards mode corrects the display issues.

You can see this by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> in IE 9 to show the *Developer Tools* and along the header of this portion of the window it states *Document Mode: Quirks*. If you select *Internet Explorer 9 standards* the menu displays as expected.

You should run your site through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsyndicateplus.com%2Fscript%2Fsyp%2Findex.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) (for example) and correct the errors and the page should be rendered as expected. Valid markup makes browsers happy - especially IE. If you then load  corrected page in IE 9, it should render in Standards mode and not revert to Quirks mode.

Comment: This is interesting! Is it possible to disable quirks mode by default? So anybody can see my page normal? Otherwise I need to make a new CSS for every page specially for IE

Comment: This is interesting! I've changed the meta tag and it shows up good except the margin of my page and the position of the drop down list. <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /> I will look at what I can do

Comment: [It is possible](http://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-trigger-standards-mode-in-IE9-but-not-IE8) but I do not recommend it at all. It isn't a case that you need to offer different CSS for IE, you need to correct the HTML. Having a [valid Doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctype) and markup that conforms to that Doctype is the correct approach. Browsers will not have to "guess" what your intention is, which is what is happening in IE.

Comment: Well I will have a look at the errors, but I don't have much time to finish the website so I don't really mind the errors, am more like after nasty fixes.

Comment: Fair enough :-) I should mention that valid markup would have meant that this problem would probably never have happened! It also reduces the inconsistencies across browsers since each browser rendering engine will "guess" differently when given invalid markup.